# Can I use logic to choose which table to make a view from in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table, call it "Overdue_Accounts" I want to make a view that checks if there is a record, customerID in that table. If it doesn't, I want the data to come from another table, "Accounts".

So, something like:

```
IF customerID IS IN Overdue_Accounts 
   THEN 
      SELECT customerID, Overdue as Amt 
      FROM Overdue_Accounts 
ELSE 
    SELECT customerID, Balance as Amt  
    FROM Accounts
```

Accounts would have every `customerID`. Here's a sample of what I'm looking for:

**Accounts**:

```
customerID |  Balance
001        |  100.00
002        |  200.00
003        |  300.00
004        |  400.00
005        |  500.00
```

**Overdue_Accounts**:

```
customerID |  Overdue 
003        |  5.00
```

**Results**:

```
customerID |  Amt  
001        |  100.00
002        |  200.00
003        |  5.00
004        |  400.00
005        |  500.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `union all` and `not exists()`:

```
SELECT customerID, Overdue as Amt 
FROM Overdue_Accounts 
union all
SELECT customerID, Balance as Amt
FROM Accounts a
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from Overdue_Accounts o
  where o.customerId = a.customerid
  )
order by customerid
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QLSLP99762

returns:

```
+------------+--------+
| customerID |  Amt   |
+------------+--------+
|        001 | 100.00 |
|        002 | 200.00 |
|        003 | 5.00   |
|        004 | 400.00 |
|        005 | 500.00 |
+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Just tried it with my data, exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` function in combination with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    Accounts.customerID,
    COALESCE(Overdue_Accounts.Overdue, Accounts.Balance) AS Amt, 
FROM Accounts
LEFT JOIN Overdue_Accounts ON Overdue_Accounts.customerID = Accounts.customerID
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures we try to get an `Overdue_Accounts` row for each `Account`.

The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is non-null:

- If we find an `Overdue_Accounts` row, then `Overdue_Accounts.Overdue` is not null and we return it.
- It we don't find an `Overdue_Accounts` row, we return `Accounts.Balance` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `customerID` is unique in both tables, you can try

```
SELECT 
  a.customerID, 
  COALESCE(o.Overdue, a.Balance) AS Amt 
FROM 
  Accounts a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Overdue_Accounts o ON a.customerID = o.customerID
```